# SOAP Webservice Calls in a Laravel Web Application: Queue, Error Handling and Retries

Tags: laravel, soap, laravel-queue

I am building an ecommerce webapp with Laravel where users can buy stuff, nothing unusual.

**The interesting thing is that the webapp should POST the orders to a webservice in an external server**.

For this requirement I need: **Queuing, Error Handling and Retrying** for the requests that could fail.

What I have done before, years ago, is to create an [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#generating-commands) which collects the orders (Order::where('sap_status',0)->get()) and loop through that collection.

So for each Order I make the SOAP call and flag the sap_status = 1, if the call has completed successfully.

Then I created a Laravel Job that runs every X minutes and calls the artisan command mentioned above.

So, the question: is this a good approach to this requirement? how would this be done better or improved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the combination of Laravel Jobs + Commands + flags in DB will do the trick.

In order to improve, you can start using Laravel Queues, and launch that job in a Q (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues).

Usually the processing and dispatching of the jobs is done in async mode (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-jobs).

If needed, you can always launch the job in sync mode(not in a Q)
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#synchronous-dispatching

On top of that, you can use Redis in order to manage the Q (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#redis).

The setup is really easy with Laravel both locally and on the server.

For the SOAP part, it would be the best to use directly the PHP SOAP, or create a wrapper on top of it, then focus into correctly handling errors/exceptions/success in order to keep the flags updated on the orders.